# ArcGIS Online Print Template Legend Override

Tags: arcgis-online, legend, printing

I have question that some of us in the forum raised in Stack Exchange in regards to the appearance word override in the legend (map). It seems the the map issued the legend (ArcGIS Online Basic Viewer) for Felda correctly (divided into different groups).

However, symbology for my feature hosted layers such as BN winning margin and 2013 Coalition winners, the word override appears everywhere in the legend. This issue also appeared when I built a WebApp builder configured for printing.

The solutions that was presented on the stack exchange that requires coding is mind boggling. Can anyone explain in simple GIS terms where possible on how this legend truly shows the values that ought to be?

[image]